# Replace css background-image: url(...) with <img> tag and keep scrolling over effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I want to add alt tags to images on my website to improve SEO. The problem is I'm embedding them using CSS *background-image: url(...)*.

It creates the desired scrolling effects (see below), but is not good for SEO.

Current code:

```css
.text {
  margin: 200px 20px;
}
.image-background {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  margin-left: -1500px;
  margin-right: -1500px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 3500px;
}
.image1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
.image2 {
  background-image: url(http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Cats/cats-149a.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class='image-background image1'></div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class='image-background image2'></div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
```

**The question is: how do I add `<img>` tags with `alt` properties without breaking the visual appearance?**

Edit:

I tried using <img> with css *position:fixed* but can't get it to work well **with more than one image** ([my broken jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ssobczak/szezjczq/2/)).

Edit 2:

These images are part of website content, *not* layout. They deserve alt tags, I'm not trying to stuff more keywords in a "bad" way. I originally put them as backgrounds to achieve a visual effect. Now I want to fix the mistake, but without changing how the website looks like. 
I'm talking [about my photos on this blog](http://coralnotes.com/pl/ameryka-polnocna/dolina-smierci/).

Edit 3:

I'm not trying to use *only* CSS here. Any code modification, JS library or pretty much anything is fine!

Comment: you could include an image tag with css to hide it

Comment: Why not just change the actual markup in an editor ?

Comment: @JaromandaX wouldn't Google figure out that it's hidden and punish SEO score for that?

Comment: if google does that, wouldn't it also figure out that the image is used in a background? I don't know for a fact, but your argument doesn't quite work :p

Comment: @adeneo yes, but what code to write to keep the same visual appearance while using <img> tags?

Comment: @JaromandaX I know Google punishes for hidden text and links, see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en. Even if it doesn't do that for images, I would prefer to be on the safe side. I don't know how Bing / Yandex / DuckDuckGo / others behave and what is Google planning for the future.

Comment: to get the same effect using `<img>` is possible, but quite a bit more complex, using `position:fixed` and appropriate z-index manipulation it should be achievable

Comment: @JaromandaX Tried that, but it's problematic with more than one image (see the updated jsfiddle in the question). This is as far as I managed to get with position:fixed - https://jsfiddle.net/ssobczak/szezjczq/2/

Comment: If it is appropriate for the image to be a *background* image, then it is not appropriate to give it `alt` text. `alt` text is for images which convey information to the user (without duplicating content already on the page). If your images **are** conveying such information, then they really shouldn't be background images in the first place. (Note that keyword stuffing for search engines is a terrible idea, and you should read http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html before writing alt text)

Comment: @Quentin right, these images are part of website content, *not* layout. I originally put them as backgrounds to achieve a visual effect. Now I want to fix the mistake, but without changing how the website looks like. I'm talking about [this page](http://coralnotes.com/pl/ameryka-polnocna/dolina-smierci/).

Comment: @ssobczak — None of the images there appear to convey any real information.

Comment: @Quentin This is a travel blog. The article is about where we went and how was it. The images are conveying exactly that information. They're not layout shadows / sprites / background color. I'd like them to be indexed by search engines. Can you help?

Comment: Don't the large paragraphs of text convey that information?

Comment: @Quentin No, Google and Bing do *not* index background images at all, doesn't matter how much text is around. I'm asking a technical question about how to follow [Google Image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124231/discussion-between-ssobczak-and-quentin).

Comment: I can't see a way to do this only with CSS at the current spec. You could achieve the behavior you want with a little help from JS.

Comment: @Diego Andrade Use of JS is perfectly fine! I'll edit the question to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

This method doesn't change the visibility of the images, so I think there's no issues about SEO at all. But it is more complex and have the caveat that only one image can appear per once. So the text's div must to fill the entire screen resulting in a big padding.

```js
$(function(){
  var texts = $('.text');
  var oldY = 0;
  
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var y = window.scrollY;
    
    texts.each(function(){
      var text = $(this);
      
      if(y >= text.offset().top)
        text.next().addClass('active');
      else
        text.next().removeClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.text{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 600px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.background-img img{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.background-img.active img{
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class="background-img active">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Image 1">
</div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class="background-img">
  <img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Cats/cats-149a.jpg" class="background-img" alt="Image 2">
</div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
```

## Method 2

This is simpler, and to say the truth it's almost the same idea from your original code. The difference is that as soon as the page loads, the images are hidden and then copied as background images for their parent divs. The advantage is that you can have more then one image visible at the same time, which is a better effect.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.background-img img').each(function(){
    var img = $(this).hide();
    img.parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + img.prop('src') + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.text{
  padding: 200px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.background-img{
  height: 400px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class="background-img">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Image 1">
</div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
<div class="background-img">
  <img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Cats/cats-149a.jpg" class="background-img" alt="Image 2">
</div>
<div class='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolores...
</div>
```